# Creating a new Cookie in PHP based on existing Cookie data

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies

I have an ASP.NET Login App that creates a cookie called 'ASP_LOGIN77' and gives the cookie a value.

I would like to create a new Cookie using this existing Cookie's data and called it 'PHP_LOGIN77' as I am using PHP to create this cookie.

How would I do this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
 setcookie("PHP_LOGIN77",$_COOKIE['ASP_LOGIN77'], time()+3600);
```

remember to do this before you send any html You can find reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

EDIT - to remova a cookie set the time to a negative value

```
 setcookie("PHP_LOGIN77","", time()-3600);
```

Comment: Hi Nicola. I rejigged to: `setcookie($_COOKIE['ASP_LOGIN77'], "PHP_LOGIN77", time()+3600);` however my new cookie has the value/name data the wrong way around. So the *Name* is the long string and the *Value* is PHP_LOGIN77. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Thank you, Nicola. I will take a look just now.

Comment: Fixed: `setcookie("PHP_LOGIN77",$_COOKIE['ASP_LOGIN77'], time()+3600*24*30*12);`

Comment: Also, final question, how do I destroy my cookie?

Comment: Many thanks for your help here, Nicola. Means so much. I have now set yours as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

1 retrevie the ASP_LOGIN77 cookie :

```
$coookie = ($_COOKIE["ASP_LOGIN77"]);
```

2 start a new cookie

setcookie("PHP_LOGIN77", $coookie);

-> expire time: 1 year

setcookie("PHP_LOGIN77", $coookie, time()+60*60*24*365);

Explanation: current time stamp + number of seconds in a yer (60*60*24*365).

Comment: This works great!! Can you confirm how I set the expiry time to 1 Year?

Comment: Many thanks for the follow-up to my query. This solution also works great. Thanks